# geom_area with a grouping variable spread across multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Basically my data looks something like this,

```
Year, group1, group2, group3
1999, 500,    1200,   1700
2000, 700,    3000,   2000
2001, 500,    4500,   2500
```

I want to have a stacked `geom_area` chart. If possible, without the use of libraries outside of `dplyr`

An example of the desired output:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show an example of your desired output

Comment: @GuedesBF https://i.imgur.com/79pbq7m.png

Comment: Your mention to 'a single row' in the tittle is confusing. Please see if I got it right in the answer

Comment: I changed your title to a more informative one. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do it all within the tidyverse. Use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to get the data in the right format, with a value variable and a grouping variable(here "name"). Use ggplot with the `fill` aesthetic mapped to the grouping variable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(!Year)%>%
ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=value, fill=name))+
geom_area()
```

[image]